# Push notification using FCM for web app in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I have previously worked on push notifications with FCM for android app. From Firebase console i got server key to which my backend program hits when the notification were expected to be delivered. Also I could easily get the device token from the console(on client side) to which the server would send the push messages.

Now in similar way i would like to implement web push notification using FCM. Unfortunately, could not find FCM set up and implementation documentation using ruby. Besides bit confused as to how i can get the device token for web client to whom i would like to send push message/notification. What things do i need to look at and that i am missing?

I have come across web push gem and terms like VAPID keys and service worker but still confused how they work with FCM. If anyone could help me out with what i should be looking at and what i am missing. Thanks for reading this far.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the FCM token for a device is only supported in client-side code. For web applications, see the documentation on [getting the registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token). You can then pass the token from the client to Ruby backend, where you can store and use it to send a notification to that specific client.

To send a message to the token from your Ruby code, you can call the [FCM REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#rest), after providing proof that your request is authorized with one of the methods outlined in the docs on [authorizing send requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server).

If you're having trouble making this work for your use-case, it's more likely that someone can help if you edit your question to show what you tried based on the above information and other existing resources.